# wget: Unsupported scheme on non-http URL

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I have the following line in my shell script:

```
export URL=file://myhost/system.log
wget -v $URL
```

When I tried to run the script it give me the following error:

```
file://myhost/system.log: Unsupported scheme.
```

Does it mean wget supports http and ftp ONLY?

Comment: Are you using Solaris ? Amiga ? Amstrad CPC 464 ?

Comment: @sputnick I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Are you in fact looking for the option `wget -i file` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`man wget` shows:

> It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as retrieval
>   through HTTP proxies.

Try curl, it supports file URLs. Also note you probably want three slashes here. Two belong to the protocol indicator (file://) and one belongs to the path (/myhost/system.log)

```
export URL=file:///myhost/system.log
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! the curl doesn't work, it gives me: `curl: <37> Couldnt open file /myhost/system.log` and I am sure the file is there. I also try three slashes there but no luck

Comment: You need to specify the full path to the file.

Comment: Er wait ... are you trying to use this across the network? As in, `myhost` is a hostname other than the one the script is running on?

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can't use the file:// scheme, as you need some sort of network transport to the remote host. I.e., the remote host will need to make the file available via HTTP, FTP, SSH tunnel, whatever.

Answer (score 3):

wget for windows doesn't support https

> unsupported scheme

tested : GNU Wget 1.9.1, a non-interactive network retriever

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 mistakes :

- `wget` doesn't support file:// scheme
- with `Linux`, the variables are called like `"$URL"`, not `%URL%` like windows