# How to download a file through FILE URI scheme in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wget: Unsupported scheme on non-http URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387970/wget-unsupported-scheme-on-non-http-url)

For example:

```
export URI=file:///myhost/system.log
```

How to download the system.log file from this URI in bash?

I have tried using `wget` and `curl` but they don't support the FILE URI scheme.

Comment: Are you sure? man curl says that FILE is a supported protocol

Comment: You could remove the leading "file://" with a regex expression

Comment: Asking the same question twice isn't going to make what you're trying to do possible.

Comment: You misunderstand the "file" protocol.  The file protocol cannot possibly use a hostname URL component, which is why there are 3 slashes instead of 2.  To transfer a file from another host, you need a server of some kind: HTTP, FTP, SSH, etc.  I'm guessing ssh/scp is closest to what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
export URI="file:///etc/passwd"
curl -s "$URI" > /tmp/l
cat /tmp/l
```

If you need to download a remote file, you should use another protocol (and scheme), like :

```
curl ftp://user:password@host:port/path/to/file
```

or

```
scp host:/path/to/file file
```

etc...

**NOTE**

`curl` is able to download *file scheme*, despite what you said.

Comment: It's worth noting that cUrl solves the problem for a single file, but does not extend to when you want a *recursive* download (wget's -r option).